# What software would you recommend for executing business logic via graphical drag and drop?

Tags: python

So I have been thinking about the idea of having defined blocks which *do stuff* which you can drag and drop to build actual business logic which can be executed. Do you have any recommendations on any existing software that does this?

I'm aware of Scratch, LabView and the likes, however, I am thinking of this more as a product which would operate within a specific domain - so would want to build something myself which is highly customisable.

In addition, if you do not have any resource you can point me towards - do you have any idea how this could be done, and if so, are you able to list the high-level steps on how you would approach it.

In Python would be a bonus :P

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [Google Blockly](https://developers.google.com/blockly). It allows you to define and implement domain-specific blocks to be used in a Scratch-like environment. The output is generated code in a language of choice, including Python.